# Spring Framework MVC "concurrency"?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, concurrency

AFAIK, Spring beans (version 3 and above), if not specified, all are singletons. So, my concern is, for example, when using `@Repository` (in classes that access database resources) or `@Service` (in classes that perform validations and business logic), these objects would be available to all of the users in the application in case accessed concurrently?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, these objects would be accessed concurrently. So they must be coded in a thread-safe way. But this is trivial to do, since they're usually stateless, except for their dependencies which are injected at startup time by Spring.

Comment: So, they will be no "singletons"? I mean, I just want that they would be not, because in a multi-user application, those classes will manipulate different values for each different user, so it doesn't makes sense that they will be singletons.

But, as I stated before, AFAIK, annotating a class with `@Repository` or `@Service`, for instance, make them singletons by default...so this is my main concern: if everytime I call/invoke them, I will have a different instance...or the same instance?

Comment: They will be singletons by default. So you'll get a single instance every time. But that doesn't matter, since they don't access any shared state. A repository executes  database queries and returns data to the services. Services use these data and return them to the layer. Everything is in local variables, and you can thus have several client requests being handled by the same singleton concurrently.

Comment: Can you please give the comments on this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171027/is-spring-boot-mvc-controller-multithreaded