# Is using akka with a rest service pointless in this scenario?

Tags: java, spring, scala, spring-boot, akka

I'm exposing functionality to access user details via a rest call.

From reading this post: [Is Spring Boot MVC controller multithreaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171027/is-spring-boot-mvc-controller-multithreaded) spring boot rest services are multithreaded. Does this mean using Akka to multi-thread web services does not serve any use?

Using Java Akka will not offer any multi-threaded advantages but will offer:

1. If a rest call fails with error (e.g  404) Akka can be used to restart the rest call or kill the thread, so stopping the service.
2. If the a certain rest call is taking much of time to complete Akka can be used to kill the call after a duration of time.
3. Akka can be used to throttle requests to rest client, useful if service allows max requests in period of time.

Are my assertions correct? If I'm not concerned with these points above, should I still use Akka or use the functionality to access the user details and not wrap the it with Akka? Could Java futures be also used for these points?

Comment: This isn't specific to Spring Boot, regardless of the framework there will be a pool of HTTP threads waiting to process requests - the servlet container in use under the hood is multi-threaded by design. As with any mutli-threaded environment care must be taken when dealing mutable state and obviously that's Akka can help out. The nice thing about using Akka, or any other asynchronous processing model, is that you'll be able to free up your HTTP threads to handle further requests.