# Are Spring boot Controller methods also singleton?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am writing a Spring boot application and I have a question regarding my controller class. I read the documentation and saw that the controller is a singleton by deafult, so I have decided to save my user info in a DB and save it by session. I use the spring boot sesison managment JDBC. My question is though, if a method is also singelton. I know it seems like a foolish question but I am starting to second guess myself. I am confused if the code I have would fail if multiple users logged in with a session. Also, can I not have any variables in my methods, or should I move the logic I have here somewhere else. I really don't know.

**Java Controller Method:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit")
    public ModelAndView editTab(@RequestParam(value = "currentAppcode", required = false, defaultValue = "Appcode") String currentAppcode, 
                                @RequestParam(value = "currentAcro", required = false, defaultValue = "Arco") String currentAcro, 
                                @RequestParam(value = "currentAppname", required = false, defaultValue = "Appname") String currentAppname, 
                                HttpSession session) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        private List<Some_Object> allQueryConfig = new ArrayList<Some_Object>();

        session.setAttribute("SELECTED_APP",queryService.findDtoById(currentCode)); 
        session.setAttribute("ALL_SERVERS", queryService.serverWork() );

        allSystems.clear();

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();

        try {
            OPTApplication selected_app = (OPTApplication) session.getAttribute("SELECTED_APP");
            rc.setProxy();

            if (rc.validateUser(currentPrincipalName, selected_app.getSys_id()) != 0 || queryService.isAuditor(currentPrincipalName)) { 

                session.setAttribute("GP_SELECTED", apiRunner.runGPData(selected_app.getNumber()));


                allQueryConfig = queryService.getNonDistinctServerInfo(); 


                modelAndView.setViewName("create");

                for (AppSelectorTier current : allQueryConfig) {
                    allSystems.add(current.getSystem());

                }
            } else {
                modelAndView.setViewName("forbidden");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            modelAndView.setViewName("test");

        }
        modelAndView.addObject("currentAppName", "Application:  " + currentAppname);
        modelAndView.addObject("ary4", queryService.getServerInfo());
        modelAndView.addObject("adid", currentPrincipalName);   
        modelAndView.addObject("hasAccess", false);

        return modelAndView;
    }
```

**Another example:**

```
    public @ResponseBody List<SelectorDTO> getGPdataTaddm(@RequestBody TestApp mTestApp, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session)
            throws SQLException {
        GroupPatternDTO gp_selected = (GroupPatternDTO) session.getAttribute("GP_SELECTED");

        session.setAttribute("QUERY_CONFIG_DATA", new QueryConfigData());
        QueryConfigData query_config_data = (QueryConfigData) session.getAttribute("QUERY_CONFIG_DATA");

        List<SelectorDTO> inProgressInfo = queryService.getInfoFromInProgress(gp_selected.getCode());
        if (inProgressInfo.size() != 0) {
            gp_selected.setSels(inProgressInfo);


        } else {

            for (SelectorDTO current : gp_selected.getSels()) {
                String objectPassed = current.getDescription().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
                System.out.println("First match: ----------------------------------------------------------------------"
                        + objectPassed);

                if (queryService.getTierTypeFromObj(objectPassed).size() != 0) {
                    AppSelectorTier selectorObj = queryService.getTierTypeFromObj(taddmObjectPassed).get(0);
                    query_config_data.setName(selectorObj.getName());
                    query_config_data.setSystem(selectorObj.getSystem());
                    query_config_data.setMqlList(selectorObj.getMqllisting());
                    query_config_data.setTag1(selectorObj.getTagname_one());
                    query_config_data.setTag2(selectorObj.getTagname_two());
                    query_config_data.setMqlSelector(selectorObj.getMqllisting());
                    query_config_data.setParseInstruc(selectorObj.getParseinstruction());
                    query_config_data.setTaddmObject(selectorObj.getTaddmobj());



                }

            }
        }
        session.setAttribute("GP_SELECTED", gp_selected);
        session.setAttribute("QUERY_CONFIG_DATA", query_config_data);
        return gp_selected.getSels();

    }
```

I am unsure if this is a good pracice or if for my usecase this is fine?

Comment: Look at these answers: [Is Spring Boot MVC controller multithreaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171027/is-spring-boot-mvc-controller-multithreaded)

Comment: It should be a user in one session. Why multiple user share the same session